# Alamofire prints "Optional(data)", how can I get rid of "Optional"

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, swift4

I have seen this post a bunch but I can't find any that relate to the newest versions of Swift or Alamofire.  I am new to swift and I am trying to parse a json file but it keeps printing `Optional(*the data*)`.  I understand this has something to do with types not being checked but I cannot figure it out exactly.

```
Alamofire.request("url", encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .responseJSON { response in
            //to get JSON return value
            if let result = response.result.value {
                 let JSON = result as! [[String:Any]]
                print(JSON[0]["price_usd"])

            }

    }
```

I also tried an if statement in the line `let JSON = result as! [[String:Any]]` but that did not help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't the unwrapping of `result`, but rather that the subscript operator to retrieve something from a `Dictionary` is always an "optional". I'd suggest you read up on optionals in [The Swift Programming Language: The Basics: Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330). Also see [the `Dictionary` overview documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary).

Anyway, your example, if you're really getting an array of dictionaries and you want to unwrap the optional value returned from the subscript operator for `price_usd` key of the first dictionary. So use `if let` or `guard let` to unwrap that optional:

```
Alamofire.request("url", encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
    .responseJSON { response in
        guard let result = response.result.value as? [[String: Any]],
            let usd = result.first?["price_usd"] as? Double else {
                print("not found")
                return
        }

        print(usd)
}
```

Or, if `price_usd`'s value was stored as a `String` in the JSON (i.e. with quotation marks around it):

```
Alamofire.request("url", encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
    .responseJSON { response in
        guard let result = response.result.value as? [[String: Any]],
            let string = result.first?["price_usd"] as? String,
            let usd = Double(string) else {
                print("not found")
                return
        }

        print(usd)
}
```

Note, I have studiously avoided any `as!` forced unwrapping, because the app would unceremoniously crash if the key wasn't found. Also note that I've eliminated `[0]` subscript operator, which will crash if the array was empty) and instead used the `first` function, with optional chaining.

Answer (score 0):

```
var errorUnwrapped: String?

errorUnwrapped = response.result.error?.localizedDescription

print(errorUnwrapped)
```

The output is : Optional("The Internet connection appears to be offline.") while

```
print(errorUnwrapped!)
```

The output is : The Internet connection appears to be offline.